# Spring Security with JWT configuration problem

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I'm developing spring boot app with JWT. When I try permit all to 2 endpoints it isnt working. All api is secured and requires token. 
Please help me write configuration. Here is my code:

**Security config:**

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class AdapterJWTSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors()
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user/signIn", "/user/addUser").permitAll()
            .and()
                .anonymous()
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
            .and()
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManagerBean()));

   }

}
```

I tried to do this in 2 spring security configurations but it didnt work.

**JwtFilter:**

```
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

public JWTAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager) {
    super(authManager);
}

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req,
                                HttpServletResponse res,
                                FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String token = req.getHeader(JwtConstants.HEADER_STRING);


    if (token == null) {
        try {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        } catch (JwtException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return;
    }

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(req, res);


    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}

private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    String token = request.getHeader(JwtConstants.HEADER_STRING);
    if (token != null) {
        Claims claims = validateToken(token);
        if (claims != null) {
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(claims, null, new ArrayList<>());
        }
        return null;
    }
    return null;
}

private Claims validateToken(String token) {
    Claims claims = null;
    try {
        return Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(JwtConstants.SECRET)
                .parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

**Controller**

If it could be helpful

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/user/")
public class UserController {
private UserService userService;

public UserController(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}

@PostMapping("addUser")
public List<String> addUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user,BindingResult bindingResult) {
    return userService.addNewUser(user, bindingResult);
}

@PostMapping("signIn")
public List<String> generate(@Valid @RequestBody UserRequestLogin user) {
    return userService.signIn(user);
  }
}
```

Comment: You send a token when you call your rest ?

Comment: @TinyOS no, I want to access to /signIn and /addUser without token and i get 403 forbidden

Comment: @Morthan What error do you get? 401 or 403?